# How can I display an animated GIF loaded from the camera roll in an iOS React Native app

Tags: ios, react-native, animated-gif, camera-roll

I have an iOS react native app where I load images from the CameraRoll and display them in another view.

This works fine for most images, but when an image is an animated GIF, the image displays, but it is not animated.  I want to be able to show the animated original, not a static thumbnail.

The image information returned from the CameraRoll is of the form:

```
{
  filename: "test animated gif 1.gif",
  height: 480,
  isStored: true,
  playableDuration: 0,
  uri: "assets-library://asset/asset.GIF?id=8627D49D-CF91-414A-94DA-035F46850867&ext=GIF",
  width: 480
}
```

I display this in an image component:

```
<Image
  source={{uri: asset.uri}
  style={{
    width: 300,
    height: 225,
    borderRadius: 15,
  }}
/>
```

As I said, a static version of the GIF will display - I believe this is one of the automatic thumbnails iOS generates of CameraRoll images.

The URI seems like a dynamic accessor sort of URI, and not a link to a specific file, and that the Image component is picking a thumbnail, as per the React Native docs.

Is there a way to force ReactNative to access the original asset file of the GIF?

Additional info:

- I can successfully display animated GIFs loaded from `http://` URIs, but that does not help me.
- I have explored using other filesystem tools like ReactNativeFetchBlob to access or display the file and the URI remains the same `assets-library://` URI.
- I have tried a different image display component (react-native-fast-image), but this also simply displays the static version of the GIF.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with how you're formatting your Image source code. React Native renders network images primarily using `uri` within the image source so they can load later than using `require`. Try out using require instead.

```
<Image
  source={require('/react-native/img/favicon.png')}
 />
```

More info:  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image

Comment: Doesn't `require` require a string to a static resource?  I'm dynamically loading assets from the CameraRoll, and as far as I understand, `require` will not work.